# Group child list into single parent object - AdventureWorks query - Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am working with the AdventureWorks database and I am using the following query :

```
 SELECT c.CustomerID, c.AccountNumber, soh.SalesOrderID, soh.SalesOrderNumber, sod.UnitPrice, sod.ProductID, p.Name
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
inner join sales.SalesOrderDetail sod on soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
inner join sales.Customer c on c.CustomerID = soh.CustomerID
inner join Production.Product p on p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
```

I have code already that populates the data like this just as it comes back:
[image]

Based on that I am wanting to merge the child list objects into a single parent to end up with a one to many structure if that makes sense.

As of right now I am hoping to use a **lambda expression** to do this.  I have tried the following code but I don't want to have to specify --> **o.CustomerID, o.AccountNumber** in the group by because i would have to specify ALL the properties of my Customer class to have access to the final select as you can see in the code.

```
                        .GroupBy(o => new { o.CustomerID, o.AccountNumber }).Select(group => new Customer2
                     {
                         CustomerID = group.Key.CustomerID,
                         AccountNumber = group.Key.AccountNumber,
                         Orders = group.SelectMany(x => x.Orders).ToList()
                     }).ToList();
```

I would like the end result to look like this for each customer:
[image]

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What should the output look like ?

Comment: It should look like the last image.  Each customer should have a list of all their orders.

Comment: your code seems to be fine, now what does not work correctly?

Comment: I don't want to have to specify each object like customerid and accountnumber in the groupby in order to have access to them in the final select